# Hook/notify when any option or setting is added or updated

Tags: hooks, options, notifications

I know about:

```
add_option_{option_name}
update_option_{option_name}
```

but these need specific option names. What I am looking for is a way to know if and when *any* option is changed (added or updated).

What I am really trying to avoid is running a query to find all option names, then running a loop through them to add both `add_option_{option_name}` and `update_option_{option_name}` for those options dynamically.
(If indeed this is the only way to do it, is this an alright way to do it?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the sources (core files, `wp-includes/option.php`) you can always find your target hook tags:

```
add_action('added_option', 'wpse230212_callback_add', 10, 2);
add_action('updated_option', 'wpse230212_callback_update', 10, 3);

function wpse230212_callback_add( $option_name, $option_value ) {
    // do stuff on add_option
}

function wpse230212_callback_update( $option_name, $old_value, $option_value ) {
    // do stuff on update_option    
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Samuel Elh. Can you also take a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230240/best-possible-way-to-get-all-options and help me please?

Comment: Just found that these actions don't trigger when you change them via the GUI. For example, changing the value of "Blog pages show at most" in Settings->Reading, doesn't fire "updated_option" or update_option_posts_per_page . Not sure if bug or intentional.